# TelegrammBot вывод кнопок из прочитанной папки

Tags: python, telegram-bot

затея такова: бот должен читать количество файлов в папке и на каждый файл выводить инлайн кнопку и выводить это общим пулом, у меня получается вывод каждой кнопки отдельным сообщением.

кто сталкивался подскажите

```
for file_name in os.listdir('folder'):
    await message.message.answer(text='ˆˆˆ', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().
                                 add(InlineKeyboardButton(f"{file_name.split('.')[1]}",
                                                          callback_data=f'{file_name}')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штош. Смотрите что вы делаете, запускаете цикл по файлам в папке и на каждую итерацию отправляете сообщение. Так что код делает то что он и должен делать.
Как фиксить?
Просто вынесите отправку сообщения из цикла.

```py
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
for file_name in os.listdir('folder'):
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(f"{file_name.split('.')[1]}", callback_data=f'{file_name}'))

await message.answer(text='ˆˆˆ', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! выручили